# Gradle sync in progress won't finish

Tags: android-studio

I am attempting to migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse and have newly installed v0.8.0 (updated to v0.8.2) Android Studio. I cannot get Gradle to finish syncing. I have tried restarting the application and reading various answers everywhere including here on StackOverflow.

I have included a idea.log below, I'm not sure if it is useful. There's more but I couldn't paste the whole thing.

```
> 
2014-08-05 10:40:55,922 [  94335]   INFO - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Importing excluded root 'source_root(C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/BaseGameUtils/build)' for content root 'file://C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/BaseGameUtils' of module 'BaseGameUtils' 
2014-08-05 10:40:55,923 [  94336]   INFO - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Importing content root 'C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/google_play_services_froyo/libproject' for module 'libproject' 
2014-08-05 10:40:55,923 [  94336]   INFO - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Importing excluded root 'source_root(C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/google_play_services_froyo/libproject/.gradle)' for content root 'file://C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/google_play_services_froyo/libproject' of module 'libproject' 
2014-08-05 10:40:55,923 [  94336]   INFO - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Importing excluded root 'source_root(C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/google_play_services_froyo/libproject/build)' for content root 'file://C:/Users/XXX/SkyDrive/workspace/google_play_services_froyo/libproject' of module 'libproject' 
2014-08-05 10:40:56,415 [  94828]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 275 ms 
2014-08-05 10:40:56,416 [  94829]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2014-08-05 10:40:56,416 [  94829]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms 
2014-08-05 10:46:40,477 [ 438890]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:16384, filtered:8176 
2014-08-05 10:54:08,569 [ 886982]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:32768, filtered:16967 
2014-08-05 10:54:36,414 [ 914827]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:49152, filtered:27454 
2014-08-05 10:55:08,059 [ 946472]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:65536, filtered:37942 
2014-08-05 10:55:57,283 [ 995696]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:81920, filtered:48317 
2014-08-05 10:56:29,933 [1028346]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:98304, filtered:58698 
2014-08-05 10:57:00,543 [1058956]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:114688, filtered:69077 
2014-08-05 11:00:09,281 [1247694]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:131072, filtered:78600 
2014-08-05 11:01:34,618 [1333031]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:147456, filtered:88166 
2014-08-05 11:02:34,206 [1392619]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:163840, filtered:98057 
2014-08-05 11:03:51,512 [1469925]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:180224, filtered:107389 
2014-08-05 11:05:06,966 [1545379]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:196608, filtered:116798 
2014-08-05 11:06:16,132 [1614545]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Change requests:212992, filtered:126086
```

Comment: There's nothing suspicious in that log file. Usually when Gradle takes a long time to sync it's because it's downloading dependencies from the network, and the network is either slow or stuck.